# Loop examples in bash

Tags: bash, control-flow

Any examples for "loop" in bash?

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
```

AND

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

AND

```
# {START..END..INCREMENT}
for i in {0..10..2}; do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

AND

```
for i in $(seq 1 3 20); do echo "Welcome $i times"; done
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 7 times
Welcome 10 times
Welcome 13 times
Welcome 16 times
Welcome 19 times
```

AND

```
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ )); do echo "Welcome $c times..."; done
Welcome 1 times...
Welcome 2 times...
Welcome 3 times...
Welcome 4 times...
Welcome 5 times...
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: "How do I use a for loop to do X" is a question; "Examples of loops" isn't, you can just search for a tutorial

Comment: I want to collect examples for "bash loop" - it could be very usefull!

Answer (score 4):

The for is superflous:

```
echo -e "\n"{1..5}

1 
2 
3 
4 
5

echo -e "\nWelcome "{1..5}" times"

Welcome 1 times 
Welcome 2 times 
Welcome 3 times 
Welcome 4 times 
Welcome 5 times
```

a recursive function:

```
toN () { max=$2 ; cur=$1; echo $cur; if (( cur < max )); then toN $((cur+1)) $max ; fi }
toN 0 5
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

a while-loop would be a bit boring, wouldn't it?

```
i=0; while ((i < 4)); do echo $((++i)); done ;
```

An not so very well known interactive loop in bash can be build with `select`:

```
select x in cat lolcat foo bar quit
do
  echo $x
  if [[ "$x" == "quit" ]]
  then
    break
  fi
done 

1) cat
2) lolcat
3) foo
4) bar
5) quit
#? 1
cat
#? 2
lolcat
#? 2
lolcat
#? 1
cat
#? 5
quit
```